# How reliable is on-the-fly IP checking?

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, geoip

I have a script that takes a set of URLs, grabs a random proxy, and pings the URL via the proxy. A few milliseconds before I make the request, I check the source of the proxy using the `geoip` library so that I can record the location of where the request was made from.

How reliable is this approach? I understand that proxies can shift locations, so there will always be a margin of error, but I'm trying to better assess how wide that margin is and how I may be able to improve my approach in general.

EDIT: I understand this may be subject to opinion, which is why I'm trying to assess the margin of error involved, not receive a yes/no answer.

Example:

```
import random
from geoip import geolite2 as geo_ip

proxy = random.choice(proxy_list)

proxy_locale = geo_ip.lookup(proxy).country

proxy_data = {"http" : "http://%s" % proxy_ip}

r = requests.head(url,proxies=proxyDict)

# Reliable?
status_for_locale = url : {'status' : r.status_code, 'locale' : proxy_locale}
```

Comment: Interesting question. If you don't get a good answer, or it gets closed, take it  to http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-country-database country lookup has 99.8% accuracy according to their site. Your code uses GeoLite, which has "lower" accuracy. How much lower is unknown.